# I cant remove a datetime object from my set?

Tags: python, datetime, set, list-comprehension, python-datetime

```
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20)]

for d in dateset:
 if d.weekday() == 0:
  dateset.discard(d)
```

So as you can see I want to remove any datetime object that has a `weekday()` of 0.

However the above code throws the error `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you cannot remove items from a set while iterating over it. You should think of a different solution

Comment: A piece of feedback on your question: I see from the comments on the accepted answer that you wanted to create this list directly, rather than actually wanting to remove items from a set. As a result, most of the answers aren't actually giving you what you really wanted. Next time you should provide information about the core problem you want to solve - not just the small technical issue in your solution. This will help you get better answers.

Comment: @PirateNinjas Thanks for the feedback! Will definitely heed your advice.

Comment: Related to what @PirateNinjas said, I recommend these two resources for familiarizing yourself with the XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thank you, this thread has been very helpful in more ways than one. I am going to check this out and adopt it going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating the set then removing items, you could just only put items into the set that you want in the first place.

### Code:

```
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20) if (base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).weekday() != 0])
```

### Output:

```
>>> dateset
{datetime.date(2019, 12, 4),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 5),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 6),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 7),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 8),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 10),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 11),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 12),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 13),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 14),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 15),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 17),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 18),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 19),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 20),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 21),
 datetime.date(2019, 12, 22)}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Would `dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20) if (base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).weekday() != 0 *and 6*])` also work?

Comment: In order to compare `weekday()` to two values, you need to do something like the following: `dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20) if (base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).weekday() not in [0, 6]])`

Comment: This is because `and 6` would evaluate the truth value of the integer `6` itself - which is always `True` - rather than checking if `weekday() != 6`.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over an object which alters it's size during runtime, i.e. you iterate over `dateset` while discarding items from it in the loop with `dateset.discard(d)`.

Get another iterator, say for example `for idx in range(len(dateset)):` to iterate over and remove the items from `dateset` accordingly.

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer. Clearly the poster is newer to these concepts and is unlikely to benefit from this advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different set to collect the entries to be removed:

```
import datetime
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20)])
remove = set()

for d in dateset:
 if d.weekday() == 0:
  remove.add(d)
dateset -= remove
print(dateset)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're iterating over the thing you're changing (as the error tells us). A way you could achieve what you're going for is a set-comprehension. Like this:

```
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20)])

dateset = {d for d in dateset if d.weekday() != 0}
```

Note that we've inverted the condition to `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove items from the set if you're looping over it. Either use a `for` loop and add the item to the set if the weekday is not 0

```py
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set()
for x in range(20):
    date = base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
    if date.weekday() != 0:
        dateset.add(date)
```

or use a list comprehension like this:

```py
base = datetime.date.today()
dateset = set([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(20) if (base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).weekday() != 0])
```